# Etiqueta audio html5 no se reproduce en iOS

Tags: html5, ios, audio

Tengo una pagina web que carga un contenido de audio con la etiqueta `<audio>`
El audio se reproduce en Android y Windows sin problema pero en iOS 10.3.3 no se puede reproducir

```
<audio controls="true"> <source src="http://192.168.1.25:8080/" preload="none"  type="audio/mpeg" autoplay></audio>
```

Con cualquier navegador de iOS (firefox, chrome,safari)no funciona.
¿Cual es el problema?
Gracias, un saludo

Comment: El streaming de audio lo genero con el vlc emitiendo mp3

Answer (score 3):

iOS impide la reproducción automática del audio (ignora el atributo `autoplay`), lo que supongo es la fuente de tu problema. Tampoco puedes disparar la reproducción ante un evento `onLoad` o similares, pero sí ante un `onClick`.

La lógica de Apple es que, sin una iniciativa por parte del usuario, no se debe comenzar la reproducción, porque eso implica una descarga (de los datos del audio o vídeo), que puede acarrear costes en la tarifa de datos del usuario. Por tanto debe ser el usuario quien, conscientemente, inicie la reproducción.

Deberías añadir por tanto a la página algún mensaje del estilo "Si estás en iOS, para iniciar la reproducción del audio toca aqui" y tener un atributo `onclick="document.miAudio.play()`

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta. El autoplay aunque lo quite sigue sin reproducir audio, por lo que veo me aconsejas que cree un evento que dispare el audio, eso intentaré hacer.

Comment: hice un boton para reproducir el audio en iOS pero resulta que me funciona con ficheros mp3 pero NO con la fuente de un streaming
`<audio controls="controls" id="linkAudio"> <source src="http://192.168.1.25:8080" preload="none"  type="audio/mpeg" >Dont Support</audio>`
`<script type="text/javascript">
  var audio = document.getElementById("linkAudio");
</script>
   <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="audio.play()" >play iOS</button> `

¿Podria Reproducir streaming con la etiqueta audio en iOS?En Android y Windows el streaming funciona perfectamente pero en iOS no va